# How to limit results in elasticsearch by term

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying Elasticsearch to get a list of 50 matching websites. Ideally, I'd like to get 50 relevant matches from 50 different websites.

My problem is that sometimes the search results contain mostly matches from one website.

Is it possible to create a query that returns 50 results that are all unique with regard to the field that stores the website's name?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best way to do this going forward is to use the top hits aggregator:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

The approach I used before top hits aggregator was definitely a hack, but surprisingly worked well. Just query for 10x the number of docs you need and collapse down client side, preferably using the node client to reduce the network overhead of the likely larger payload.